# how to create a chrome extension to get the number of installed plug-ins on my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, browser-plugin, browser-extension

how to create a chrome extension to get the number of installed plug-ins on my Browser?
Hello Everybody,
I wanna create a google chrome extension which gives me the total number of installed plug-ins on my browser. i am new in this developing field. where can i learn the advanced level javascript code to develop my skill. please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [`navigator.plugins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins)

```js
[].forEach.call(navigator.plugins, function(plugin,index) {
  console.log(index, plugin.name, plugin.filename, plugin.description)
})
```

Comment: @KaziNayem _"but i am not clear."_ Can you describe what is not clear?

Comment: actually i didn't understand your code. could you please give me in a brief... i'm totally new in plug-ins development. i can't seek tutorial which can help me...

Comment: **it's working. thanks a lot** but i wanted to know that this code will work as a extension. how can i implement this code as chrome extension. @guest271314

Comment: @KaziNayem See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted